# Entity Framework not filling a varbinary property

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, web-config

Hi I have a table in the database call Brand which has a column name img which is a varbinary(max) type. 
Also I have an Entity Framework project which makes all the calls to the database.
I have store the byte array in this column, and the save process works pretty good, but when I do query the objects, this property comes whit a null value. although that in the data base the value is store.

is there something that I am missing? or is there a way to automatically load this data?

```
CREATE TABLE [BRAND](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[NAME] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
[LOGO] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[STATUS] [int] NOT NULL,
[EXT] [nchar](10) NULL,
[IMG] [varbinary](max) NULL
)
```

Model Definition

```
[DataContract]
public partial class BRAND
{
    public BRAND()
    {

        this.PRODUCTs = new List<PRODUCT>();
    }

    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public string LOGO { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public int STATUS { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public string EXT { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public byte[] IMG { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public virtual STATUS STATUS1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public virtual List<PRODUCT> PRODUCTs { get; set; }
}
```

Method that query the information from the database

```
public override IQueryable<BRAND> GetActive()
    {
        var query = Context.BRANDs.Where(x => x.STATUS1.ID == (int)Constants.Status.Active);
        return query;
    }
```

Comment: Please post your table structure, your class and your LINQ.

Comment: are you using table splitting?

Comment: no, not that I know. btw thanks for any help you can give me.